# Check if a class has bases

Tags: c++

Is there a way in C++ to check if a class has one or more base classes?

I am looking for a type trait that would return `true` for:

```cpp
struct X
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

but return `false` for

```cpp
struct Y : X
{
  int c;
  int d;
};
```

There doesn't seem to be any type trait for that in the standard library.

I need it to determine aggregate classes that can be decomposed in structured binding to the same number of arguments as they are initialized with in brace-initialization:

```cpp
// class X is ok:
X x = {{}, {}};    // 2 arguments
auto [m1, m2] = x; // 2 arguments

// class Y is bad:
Y y = {{}, {}, {}}; // 3 arguments, because Y has base
auto [m1, m2] = y;  // 2 arguments
```

For thus filtered types I could determine how many members they can be decomposed into in structured binding by looking at how many numbers they can be maximally brace-initialized with. The latter can be determined with SFINAE tricks; the former cannot.

This in turn can be useful in a library like this one: https://apolukhin.github.io/magic_get/index.html

Comment: Why would you need this information about a class?

Comment: Without compiler magic this isn't testable at all. I could not think of any thing a data type differ from another only while inheriting.

Comment: Define virtual function like `bool is_base() { return true; }` with `return false;` in child classes.

Comment: I take it you want to do this without modifying the classes? If so, I don't think it's possible yet. Types don't carry that info around with them.

Comment: This is to be able to detect in C++20 aggregates that can be braced-initialized, and decomposed in structure binding with the same number of initializers/parameters.

Comment: Then your question is an XY problem. You should add that to the question, and make it the focus. Not that detecting whether a type has bases will help, since aggregates can have base classes from c++17.

Comment: if you know the base class then it is [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). When you don't know the base, you cant. What would the information be good for? Your example with 2 / 3 arguments only works because you know both `X` and `Y`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882827/type-trait-for-aggregate-initializability-in-the-standard-library .

Comment: Why not add the technique, or link to it, where you figure out the maximal arguments the aggregate can be initialized with? That's half the problem, and it might help with figuring out the other half.

Comment: Always test for the features  you depend on, never on circumstantial evidence. If you need your classes to work with Boost.PFR then you should test for that. Or even better, don't test, and let the actual use of the classes with Boost.PFR be the test. I am sure the compiler can figure it out.